"ImportError: No module named site" with Windows 11- Using Python command in Ubuntu/Linux
I am trying to run the following command on Windows 11:
python2 tools/readMilleBinary.py mp2tst.bin 3 > mp2binary.txt
but I keep getting the error:
ImportError: No module named site
Now, I looked into this and a lot of people mentioned looking at environment variables. What I have set is the following:
**User variables:**

(Variable -> Value)

Path -> C:\Users\trbar\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;

**System Variables:**

(Variable -> Value)

PYTHONHOME -> C:\Python\Python3101
PYTHONPATH -> C:\Python\Python3101\Lib
Path -> %PYTHONHOME%;%Path

This seemed to be what people suggested, but it didn't work for me. I tried dropping "Python" in the paths as well, and that also didn't work. I do see the "site" file inside of C:\Python\Python3101\Lib, so I know it exists, but for whatever reason it's not working correctly.
I also don't know if I need to change the command for Python3 since I believe that's what I'm using, as the installation folder named itself Python3101. I can't find documentation anywhere that explains the equivalent command for python2 tools/ in Python 3.
Also- I'm running this command on Ubuntu 20.04, not from my computer's Python command line. I'm not sure if I have to download Python into Ubuntu as well somehow (maybe copy the folder(s) over into the Linux directory?). I've never had this issue before, so I don't know.
Please, any advice you have would be greatly appreciated. I just have no clue what is going wrong.

If you are only just learning the basics, you should probably ignore Python 2, and spend your time on the currently recommended and supported version of the language, which is Python 3.

Right.  You looked inside of Python3101\Lib, but that's for Python 3, not Python 2.

What is the equivalent command for Python 3? I saw that the command was calling Python 2 but I couldn't find anything equivalent to "python2 tools/" and simply replacing 2 with 3 doesn't call anything
